# Momentum conservation in the Fractional Quantum Hall Effect

Tags: topological-order, quantum-hall-effect

Generically an Abelian Fractional Quantum Hall Systems is described by chiral scalar fields $\hat{\Phi}^{\ }_{i}(t,x)$ with $i=1,\ldots,N$ and a Hamiltonian of the form
$
\hat{H}^{\ }_{0}:=
\int\limits_{0}^{L}
\mathrm{d}x\,
\frac{1}{4\pi}
\partial^{\ }_{x}\hat{\Phi}^{\mathsf{T}}
\;V\;
\partial^{\ }_{x}\hat{\Phi}
\;
$
with with $V$ a $N\times N$ symmetric and positive definite matrix. 
The chiral scalar fields obey (up to Klein Factors) the following anticommutation 
relations: $
\left[
\hat{\Phi}^{\ }_{i}(t,x ),
\hat{\Phi}^{\ }_{j}(t,x')
\right]=
-
\mathrm{i}\pi
K^{-1}_{ij}
\;\mathrm{sgn}(x-x')
$.
Here $K$ is a $N\times N$ symmetric and invertible matrix with
integer-valued matrix elements. We define electron operators of our theory by:
$\widehat{\Psi}^{\dagger}_{T}(t,x)
:=\ 
:e^{-\mathrm{i}\,T_{i}\,K^{\ }_{ij}\,\hat{\Phi}^{\ }_{j}(t,x)}:
\;,$
where the integer-valued $N$-dimensional vector $T$ determines 
the charge (and statistics) of the operator.

Now we can introduce backscattering terms of the form: 
$\hat{H}^{\ }_{\mathrm{int}}:=
-
\int\limits_{0}^{L}
\mathrm{d}x
\sum_{T\in\mathbb{L}}
h^{\ }_{T}(x)
:
\cos
\Big(
T^{\mathsf{T}} K\,\hat \Phi(x)
+
\alpha^{\ }_{T}(x)
\Big)
:.$
The real functions $h^{\ }_{T}(x)\geq0$ and
$0\leq\alpha^{\ }_{T}(x)\leq2\pi$ encode information about 
the disorder along the edge when position dependent.

*This text was partially taken from http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.3989.*

**Questions:**

Does this type of backscattering also include inelastic backscattering?
Given a particular backscattering term how do I see whether the backscattering is inelastic or elastic? If inelastic backscattering is also allowed where does the excess momentum go? Are these terms "physical"?

I am looking forward to your responses.